# How do I change the default text and color for jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I am using the jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget from 
[Eric Hynds](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget)

How do I change the default bluish text "Select options" to different text and color? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one is coming from Jquery UI css

you need to change the below class for whatever the color you need

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default{
color  :black;
}
```

**Note:**  :This may impact all other places where you have used jquery UI classes.

If you are doing via jquery you can add your custom class and add color.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I tried put your code into the style but the "Select options" is still blue. Also, do you have any idea how to change the text?

Comment: It should work...put in the correct css and make sure the page is referenced